# Grails + GAE - Issue using app.servlet.version=2.5

Tags: java, google-app-engine, grails

Updating the servlet version in application.properties to 2.5 has no affect on the generated web.xml. The generated web.xml is still version 2.4. I'm using Grails 1.2.1.

```
app.servlet.version=2.5
```

Also, if I try to execute "run-app" I get the exception below:

```
Running Grails application..
Starting AppEngine generated indices thread.
Starting reload monitor thread.
     [java] Jan 26, 2010 5:27:05 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
     [java] WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@4178460d{/,C:\Users\Taylor Leese\workspace\test-gae\web-app}
     [java] java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: grails
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:953)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1037)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:305)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1215)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
     [java]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:188)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:120)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:162)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
     [java]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
     [java] The server is running at http://localhost:8080/
```

Any ideas how to resolve these issues?

Comment: Perhaps this is the same or similar issue? http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4277

Comment: Looks like the same problem indeed. You should answer your own question :)

Comment: If the JIRA issue has Status: Resolved that means it's not in a release yet, correct?

Comment: No, the status *Resolved* means that *A resolution has been taken, and it is awaiting verification by reporter. From here issues are either reopened, or are closed*. You should report that problem when using grails 1.2 or maybe reopen the issue.

Comment: I opened a JIRA issue for this: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1895

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a `grails clean` after making the change in servlet version? At least that works on my machine (grails 1.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Ypu might want to checkout Play on GAE:
http://geeks.aretotally.in/mind/2011/1/14/play-framework-scala-gae-sammy-in-production.html